# Persistent storage: How to mount a directory in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, persistent-storage

I understand that in Kubernetes you don't want to "tie" a pod to a host, but in certain cases you might need to.

In my particular case I have a DB that lives on blockstorage which is mounted to a specific host.

What I am trying to accomplish with Kubernetes is the equivalent of a bind-mount in Docker. I want to specify the directory on the host that I need mounted in the pod, similar to this:

```
/mnt/BTC_2:/root/.bitcoin:rw
```

How do I specify the location of where I want my persistent storage to be on the node/host? Would this be a `hostPath` volume like the following:

```
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /root/.bitcoin
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /mnt/BTC_2
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to specify the directory on the host that I need mounted in the pod

That should be [documented here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)

> A hostPath volume mounts a file or directory from the host node’s filesystem into your pod. This is not something that most Pods will need, but it offers a powerful escape hatch for some applications.

Warning:

> The files or directories created on the underlying hosts are only writable by root. You either need to run your process as root in a privileged container or modify the file permissions on the host to be able to write to a hostPath volume

```
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /data
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```